# Why does Gawain leave his sword behind?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-green-knight

Gawain uses his sword to cut the ropes and free himself.

Then he appears to be running around without the sword.

Why?!

PS. I understand that he is somewhat of a moron, but leaving an excellent weapon behind and running around unarmed goes far beyond common stupidity.

Comment: https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/36474-THE-GREEN-KNIGHT-by-David-Lowery-.pdf - I can't see anything in the script that addresses it